# Why do fast queries sometimes run slowly in postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a rails app running on heroku with postgresql. My periodically slows down as traffic ramps up and I was studying NewRelic to try and figure out why so I can fix it. My attention is focused on two queries which are regularly listed in the slowest queries and the API calls that use them are always in the slow traces. When I say slow, I mean >5s or >10 seconds.

The weird thing is, these two queries are simple and they both have indexes. I've run them many times and they're always fast, and I've done SQL EXPLAIN just to be sure they are using the indexes and they are.

I was doing `heroku pg:ps` repeatedly to see if I could catch a situation where a query was running slow, and I caught one.

Normally there are only a few queries at any moment in time and they've been running for well under a second. But on one refresh of `pg:ps` I saw this:

```
   pid   |        state        |                 source                 |    username    |   running_for    |       transaction_start       | waiting |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   query                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
---------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1676234 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | -00:00:00.040657 | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.363991+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" WHERE "social_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
 1676247 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | -00:00:00.031318 | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.354652+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1676242 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia |                  |                               | f       | SELECT "social_presences".* FROM "social_presences" WHERE "social_presences"."roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY "social_presences"."id" DESC LIMIT $2
 1676262 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | -00:00:00.030612 | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.353946+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" WHERE "social_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
 1676238 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy] leader | u66h88771ibtia | -00:00:00.029444 | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.352778+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" WHERE "social_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
 1676265 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | -00:00:00.008377 | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.331711+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1676235 | idle in transaction | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:00.00381   | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.319524+00 | t       | UPDATE "social_profiles" SET "properties" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "social_profiles"."id" = $3
 1680707 | active              | puma: cluster worker 6: 3 [app]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:00.039364  | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.28397+00  | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1681369 | active              | puma: cluster worker 4: 3 [app]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:00.093883  | 2022-11-02 22:50:03.229451+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1676250 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy] leader | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:00.481337  | 2022-11-02 22:50:02.841997+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1676248 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:00.58908   | 2022-11-02 22:50:02.734254+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1680026 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 2 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:00.740878  | 2022-11-02 22:50:02.582456+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1681335 | active              | puma: cluster worker 6: 3 [app]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:01.12521   | 2022-11-02 22:50:02.198124+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1680580 | active              | puma: cluster worker 0: 3 [app]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:01.198566  | 2022-11-02 22:50:02.124768+00 | f       | SELECT "social_presences".* FROM "social_presences" WHERE "social_presences"."roblox_profile_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60, $61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70, $71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80, $81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90, $91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100, $101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108, $109, $110, $111, $112, $113, $114, $115, $116, $117, $118) ORDER BY "social_presences"."id" DESC LIMIT $119
 1681096 | active              | puma: cluster worker 4: 3 [app]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:01.40275   | 2022-11-02 22:50:01.920584+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1676231 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:01.407438  | 2022-11-02 22:50:01.915896+00 | f       | SELECT "social_profiles".* FROM "social_profiles" INNER JOIN "social_roblox_friendships" ON "social_profiles"."id" = "social_roblox_friendships"."destination_roblox_profile_id" WHERE "social_roblox_friendships"."source_roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY social_roblox_friendships.properties->'friend_frequent_rank'
 1680741 | active              | puma: cluster worker 7: 3 [app]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:01.541238  | 2022-11-02 22:50:01.782096+00 | f       | SELECT "social_presences".* FROM "social_presences" WHERE "social_presences"."roblox_profile_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60, $61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70, $71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76) ORDER BY "social_presences"."id" DESC LIMIT $77
 1676246 | active              | sidekiq 6.3.1 app [0 of 5 busy]        | u66h88771ibtia | 00:00:01.675252  | 2022-11-02 22:50:01.648082+00 | f       | SELECT "social_presences".* FROM "social_presences" WHERE "social_presences"."roblox_profile_id" = $1 ORDER BY "social_presences"."id" DESC LIMIT $2
(18 rows)
```

Here you can see the two queries. What stood out to me about this is that there are 4 queries in this list that are all >1s. I haven't caught `pg:ps` in a moment where it was >5 or >10s, but this is something. And these are the same queries that normally complete in 100 ms.

I'm struggling to debug this further. Any suggestions? Is database contention causing this? Is this just an issue when too many queries are all executed at once? How do I confidently get to the root cause.

Comment: Any way you can query pg_stat_activity directly?  pg:ps seems to omit much possibly useful infomration.

Comment: Perhaps the database machine is simply overloaded, and using a reasonably sized connection pool you can get much better performance.

Comment: A possible cause of this problem is lack of cache memory. If the data of the tables and indexes concerned are not in cache, PostGreSQL will have to mount them from disk in memory before being able to start the query... Two solution : add more RAM and reparameterize the cluster config or create covering indexes by using the INCLUDE clause... But without the query text and an EXPLAIN, we cannot help you more !